# Azure Synapse: Possible to create/deploy ONNX model to dedicated sql pool from Synapse Notebook?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-machine-learning-service

The examples I see of installing trained ONNX models to Synapse dedicated sql pool (for use with the PREDICT functionality) all originate from Azure Machine Learning Studio. E.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/machine-learning/tutorial-sql-pool-model-scoring-wizard

Can this be done from a Synapse Notebook directly, never leaving the Synapse environment?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Azure Synapse Studio workspace and go to **Manage** tab

[image]

2. Click on **SQL Pool** under **Analytics Pool** and assign one unique name. In this case **SQLPool01**

[image]

Train a model in synapse studio which includes machine learning libraries and apache spark. All the operations will be performed in Synapse Notebook.
Here the major requirement is to make ONNX supportive.
We can deploy the ONNX model to a table in SQL database pool using Synapse studio
Checkout the [repository](https://github.com/solliancenet/azure-synapse-analytics-workshop-400/blob/master/day-03/lab06-machine-learning.md#exercise-1---synapse-machine-learning-in-action) which leads to implement complete ONNX deployment using Synapse studio without coming out of that environment and using the notebook within the environment.